# How to deploy a HDP cluster without HDFS?

Tags: hadoop2, ambari, hdp

How to deploy a  HDP cluster without HDFS, as I don't want HDFS for storage and will be using in-house in-memory storage system. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

HDFS and MapReduce are the main internal part of Hadoop. They comes inbuilt with the package of Hadoop . You can not exclude HDFS while HDP cluster Deployment. You can exlcude other sevices then HDFS but you can not exclude HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

HDFS is an implementation of the Hadoop FileSystem API, which models POSIX file system behavior.

You are probably referring to Object Stores in places, often using the term Blobstore. Hadoop does provide FileSystem client classes for some of these even though they violate many of the requirements. This is why, although Hadoop can read and write data in an object store, the two which Hadoop ships with direct support for — Amazon S3 and OpenStack Swift — **cannot** be used as direct replacements for HDFS.

For further reading, [Object Stores vs Filesystems](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/filesystem/introduction.html#Object_Stores_vs._Filesystems)